# Recyclerview is lagging to much

Tags: java, android-studio

Here is my code
this is my recyclerview adapter code ..
i dnot konw why my recycler view lagging after schroll
Pleas Help ME

```
public class Recyclerview1Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recyclerview1Adapter.ViewHolder> {
  
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _data;
  
  public Recyclerview1Adapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _arr) {
   _data = _arr;
  }
  
  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   LayoutInflater _inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
   View _v = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_item, null);
   RecyclerView.LayoutParams _lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   _v.setLayoutParams(_lp);
   return new ViewHolder(_v);
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder _holder, final int _position) {
   View _view = _holder.itemView;
   
   final LinearLayout linear1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
   final LinearLayout linear2 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear2);
   final LinearLayout linear4 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear4);
   final androidx.cardview.widget.CardView cardview2 = _view.findViewById(R.id.cardview2);
   final LinearLayout linear3 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear3);
   final LinearLayout linear7 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear7);
   final ImageView imageview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
   final TextView textview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
   final TextView textview2 = _view.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
   final LinearLayout linear5 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear5);
   final TextView textview3 = _view.findViewById(R.id.textview3);
   final TextView textview4 = _view.findViewById(R.id.textview4);
   final LinearLayout linear10 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear10);
   final ImageView imageview3 = _view.findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
   
   _shapeRadius(textview1, "#000000", 6);
   _shapeRadius(textview4, "#272731", 8);
   textview1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/spartan_regular.ttf"), 0);
   textview2.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/spartan_bold.ttf"), 0);
   textview3.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/spartan_regular.ttf"), 0);
   textview4.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/spartan_bold.ttf"), 0);
   textview1.setTextSize((int)8);
   cardview2.setBackground(new GradientDrawable() { public GradientDrawable getIns(int a, int b) { this.setCornerRadius(a); this.setColor(b); return this; } }.getIns((int)18, 0xFF272731));
   duration = Double.parseDouble(allVideosList.get((int)_position).get("videoDuration").toString());
   videoDuration = stringForTime((int)duration);
   textview1.setText(videoDuration);
   path = allVideosList.get((int)_position).get("videoPath").toString();
   //using cardview programmatically inside listview is not good. use recyclerview instead of listview.
   androidx.cardview.widget.CardView cardview1 = new androidx.cardview.widget.CardView(VideoListFragmentActivity.this.getContext());
   cardview1.setCardElevation(0);
   cardview1.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF272731);
   cardview1.setRadius(18);
   ViewGroup imageParent = ((ViewGroup)imageview1.getParent()); imageParent.removeView(imageview1);
   cardview1.addView(imageview1);
   imageParent.addView(cardview1);
   textview2.setText(Uri.parse(path).getLastPathSegment());
   size = Double.parseDouble(allVideosList.get((int)_position).get("videoSize").toString());
   humanReadableSize = bytesIntoHumanReadable((long)size);
   textview3.setText(allVideosList.get((int)_position).get("formattedDate").toString());
   com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
   .load(path)
   .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(factory))
   .placeholder(R.drawable.video_background) 
   .error(R.drawable.video_background) 
   .fitCenter() 
   .into(imageview1);
   textview4.setText(humanReadableSize);
  }
  
  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
   return _data.size();
  }
  
  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   public ViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
   }
  }
 }
```

Iam trying to create a video player app after adding rcyclerview with glide image loader library , recyclerview is lagging after scroll , get all videos from storage using mediastore then add in a list and add list in recyclerview , but after load more than 100 videos recycler view is lagging to much so please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try moving stuff from `onBindViewHolder` to `onCreateViewHolder`, such as all the `setTypeface` calls. You shouldn't be calling those every time you bind.

Do you need to create those typefaces for every textview in every viewholder? Maybe you could load those once somewhere else, like in the constructor.

Why are you finding all those linearLayouts in `onBindViewHolder`? They don't seem to be used in the code.

Ultimately, though, I think most of your latency is probably coming from the
`com.bumptech.glide.Glide` component, which looks like you are loading a video for each item.  You could try creating a test loop that all it does is load all those videos using this component, and time how long it takes.